# C# - Console Application 'Drag and Drop' Crashes

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using 'EPPlus.Core' to handle XLSX sheets, and my program works fine if I manually reference a file to it (EG: "TEST.EXE DATA.XLSX"), but when I drag and drop the file on the program (TEST.EXE), it crashes it with the information seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Hi, please post your error as text

Comment: Besides that, I think EPPlus.Core cannot be found ;-)

Comment: Do you have EPPlus.Core.dll in the same folder as the exe?

Comment: How are you referencing the assembly? When you drop a file on the `.exe`, the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will be the path of the file, not the path of the `.exe`. Perhaps that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! You are right. It's because the required DLL was missing from the working (current) directory. Thank you.